# MDB data type that allows decimal points in numbers?

Tags: ms-access, database-design, field

What data types in `MDB (MS Access)` database format will allow decimal points in numbers?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Access supports a number of numeric table column types:

- Integer types: `Byte`, `Integer` and `Long Integer` (called `TINYINT`, `SMALLINT` and `INTEGER` in SQL)
- Floating point types: `Single` and `Double`  (called `REAL` and `FLOAT` in SQL)
- Fixed decimal types: `Decimal` and `Currency` (called `DECIMAL` and `MONEY` in SQL)

While floating point types are commonly used in application software, most database designs focus on the fixed decimal types instead.

- [Microsoft Access 2003 SQL data types](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/sql-data-types-HP001032248.aspx) (last version that uses MDBs exclusively)
- [Microsoft Access 2013 SQL data types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193793.aspx) (most recent version)
- [Wikibooks: JET Database/Data types](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JET_Database/Data_types)

Comment: FYI, while in Access, Float is called Single.

Comment: @TomCollins You are right. Access can sometimes be confusing, since it uses different type names between Access and SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Single and Double allow decimal places.
Integer and Long DO NOT!